# Не работает вход по ключу для нового пользователя CentOS

Tags: ssh-key, ssh, centos

В CentOS 6.5 на сервере добавил нового пользователя. Мне нужно организовать вход под этим юзером на сервер по публичному ключу.

Ключи сгенерировал на своей машине, добавил ключ в `authorized_keys`, но при коннекте у меня по-прежнему спрашивает пароль.

В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: @victor_crimea, стандартный сценарий отлова ssh-ошибок:

* `ssh -vvvT user@host` - подключаемся к той машине, к которой не можем и получаем verbose-listing. Там будет видно, какие ключи пробует передать ssh и что затем происходит.
* Проверить, что папки типа .ssh и находящиеся внутри приватные ключи имеют разрешения строго 700 - ssh без этого не коннектится.
* Заглянуть в /var/log/auth.log

Comment: @Etki, я бы последний пункт первым поставил.

Answer (score 2):

довольно часто это связано с неправильной принадлежностьи и/или правами каталога `.ssh` и/или его содержимого.

1. исправить принадленость:

   ```
   $ sudo chown -R пользователь:группа /путь/к/каталогу/.ssh
   ```

   где `группа` — это основная группа пользователя. уточнить её можно с помощью:

   ```
   $ id пользователь
   uid=номер(пользователь) gid=номер(группа) …
   ```
2. исправить права:

   ```
   $ sudo chmod -R go= /путь/к/каталогу/.ssh
   ```

---

также стоит убедиться, что вы поместили именно **публичную** часть ключа (`id_rsa.pub` или `id_dsa.pub`) в файл `authorized_keys`, и что этот файл располагается именно в каталоге `.ssh` в домашнем каталоге созданного пользователя.

---

вообще, чтобы избежать подобных вышеописанным проблем, удобнее копировать публичный ключ с помощью программы `ssh-copy-id`:

```
$ ssh-copy-id пользователь@сервер
```

Comment: Если файл ключа копирован без `ssh-copy-id`, а вручную - то ещё и нужно и `selinux` поправить: `restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`