# OpenSSH коннект под рутом

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Уже сколько статей прочитал,всеравно ничего не получается.Уже в настройках добавил возможность коннекта под рутом,перезапускал уже SSH несколько раз,всеравно пишет access denied.Подскажите в каком еще месте нужно копать?

```
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully

Apr 13 20:37:29 Johny sshd[4301]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.0.106  user=root
Apr 13 20:37:32 Johny sshd[4301]: Failed password for root from 192.168.0.106 port 50948 ssh2
```

Comment: всё как и для [любого другого пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/358789/178576). и никаких правок файла `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, перезапусков программы *sshd* и тому подобных действий — не требуется.

Comment: Почему тогда пишут везде что в конфиге нужно включать PermitRootLogin?

Comment: насколько я знаю, в дистрибутиве ubuntu (как и в большинстве других) по умолчанию этот параметр имеет значение `prohibit-password`, т.е., **«включен»**, и дополнительного «включения» не требует.

Comment: Странно конечно,уже все перепробовал всеравно не получается

Comment: «всё» — не надо. достаточно того, что изложено в ответе по ссылке выше. если сделано правильно, но не работает — изучайте логи (`/var/log/auth.log`) и вывод программы *ssh*, добавив ей «разговорчивости» с помощью опции `-v`.

Comment: Создаю нового пользователя,задаю ему пароль и без проблем захожу в система.Задаю пароль для рута и не в какую.Access denied и точка

Comment: ssh-ключ и пароль — это немного разные вещи. пользователь root не должен удалённо аутентифицироваться по паролю.

Comment: То есть обычная аутентификация с паролем не подойдет? Почему везде тогда пишут,такая же аутентификация как под обычным пользователем только указываем рута и все.

Comment: *Почему везде тогда пишут* — во-первых, не «везде». во-вторых, если подобная инструкция не содержит оговорки «ни в коем случае так не делайте», то её автор, вероятнее всего, мало задумывается о вопросах безопасности.

Comment: Ну по поводу безопасности я не беспокоюсь,сервер на виртуалке и просто для тестов

Comment: В пароле случайно нет каких нибудь "эдаких" символов. Например наблюдал, что с некторых терминалов невозможно войти под пользователем если в пароле содержится `~`

Comment: Да нет пароль простой.

Comment: Наконец то сконнектился,поправил файл sshd_config, разрешил в нем доступ под рутом и заработало